# Error: cannot coerce class ‘"lm"’ to a data.frame

Tags: class, lm, error-messaging, coerce

**Prior to running the code in question:**

```
library(car);
library(compute.es);
library(effects); 
library(ggplot2);
library(multcomp); 
library(pastecs); 
library(effectsize)
```

```
Data_Assignment7 = read.csv("Desktop/Adv. Data/Data_Assignment7.csv")
```

```
View(Data_Assignment7)
```

```
Data_Assignment7$group<-gl(3,10, labels = c("High Dose", "Low Dose", "Placebo"))
```

```
Weight_lbs <- Data_Assignment7$outcome
```

```
ggplot(Data_Assignment7, aes(group, Weight_lbs)) +
stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point", fill = "Black", colour = "Purple") +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar",width = 0.1) + labs(x = "group", y = "Weight_lbs")+
  geom_jitter(data=Data_Assignment7, aes(x=group,y=Weight_lbs), width = 0.1, color = "Red",alpha = 0.8)
```

#Data Summary

```
by(Data_Assignment7$outcome, Data_Assignment7$group, stat.desc)
```

#Check for homogeneity of variance

```
leveneTest(Data_Assignment7$outcome, Data_Assignment7$group)
```

**Keep getting ERROR MESSAGE when I run:******
Lin_reg<-lm(Data_Assignment7$model$Weight_lbs ~ Data_Assignment7$model$group, data=Data_Assignment7)
Error in as.data.frame.default(data) :
cannot coerce class ‘"lm"’ to a data.frame

**Other methods used below:**

1. Lin_reg<-lm(Data_Assignment7$model$Weight_lbs ~ Data_Assignment7$model$group, data=Data_Assignment7)
   Error in as.data.frame.default(data) :
   cannot coerce class ‘"lm"’ to a data.frame
2. Lin_reg<-lm(Data_Assignment7$model$Weight_lbs ~ Data_Assignment7$model$group, data=Data_Assignment7)
   Error in as.data.frame.default(data) :
   cannot coerce class ‘"lm"’ to a data.frame
3. Lin_reg<-lm(Data_Assignment7$model$Weight_lbs ~ Data_Assignment7$model$group, data=Data_Assignment7)
   Error in as.data.frame.default(data) :
   cannot coerce class ‘"lm"’ to a data.frame
4. Lin_reg<-lm(Data_Assignment7$model$Weight_lbs ~ Data_Assignment7$model$group, data=Data_Assignment7)
   Error in as.data.frame.default(data) :
   cannot coerce class ‘"lm"’ to a data.frame
5. Lin_reg<-lm(Data_Assignment7$model$Weight_lbs ~ Data_Assignment7$model$group, data=Data_Assignment7)
   Error in as.data.frame.default(data) :
   cannot coerce class ‘"lm"’ to a data.frame

**Please note that all of the above blocks of code were run in an RMarkdown file and and r-blocked respectively**

**Professor's example**

```
install.packages("effectsize")
install.packages("compute.es")
install.packages("effects")
```

```
library(car);
library(compute.es);
library(effects); 
library(ggplot2);
library(multcomp); 
library(pastecs); 
library(effectsize)
```

#First ANOVA

```
viagradata = read.csv("Desktop/Adv. Data/Viagra_Data.csv")
```

```
viagradata$dose<-gl(3,5, labels = c("Placebo", "Low Dose", "High Dose"))
```

```
ggplot(viagradata, aes(dose, libido)) +
stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point", fill = "White", colour = "Black") +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar",width = 0.1) + labs(x = "Dose", y = "Libido")+
  geom_jitter(data=viagradata, aes(x=dose,y=libido), width = 0.1, color = "Red",alpha = 0.8)
```

#Get data summary

```
by(viagradata$libido, viagradata$dose, stat.desc)
```

#Check for homogeneity of variance

```
leveneTest(viagradata$libido, viagradata$dose)
```

**What I am EXPECTING, see below**
#Run regression - take a look at the F-value!

```
viagraModel<-lm(libido~dose, data = viagradata)
summary(viagraModel)
```

Call:
lm(formula = libido ~ dose, data = viagradata)

Residuals:
Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max
-2.0   -1.2   -0.2    0.9    2.0

### Coefficients:
Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)     2.2000     0.6272   3.508  0.00432 **
doseLow Dose    1.0000     0.8869   1.127  0.28158
doseHigh Dose   2.8000     0.8869   3.157  0.00827 **

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.402 on 12 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4604,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.3704
F-statistic: 5.119 on 2 and 12 DF,  p-value: 0.02469